# Transfer stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a PC with an access to a sql server with database containing stored procedures. I want to copy the procedures to update a local PC.

How can I store only the stored procedures (not all database) on a usb key to update my local server ?

Maybe it's not the right way, i'm very beginner with SQL.

Edit:I'm using Microsoft SQL  Management Studio 2014

Comment: Why not open the procedures, copy the create scripts and save them as individual text files (appended with .sql)?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server then right click on DB name and click on Task->Generate Script, select only stored procedure and you will get create script.
If Oracle then use export command and try to include only stored procedures. If you have any GUI like TOAD or SQL Developer then take a script and run in local. 
If you have any other DB then tell us.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i'm using Microsoft SQL Management studio

Comment: @JohnHC I have more than 20 procedures, it will take a long time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you are using SSMS, you can do it following this steps:

1. Right click on the database
2. Select tasks, generate scripts
3. In select objects tab, select the second option "Select specific
   database objects".
4. Select only the stored procedures you want
5. Export in a single file or multiple files.

Regards.

Comment: It looks like what I'm looking for, but the generated script want to create the procedures. I already have the procedures in the other PC, I want to update them. Is there an option to do that ?

Comment: There is an additional option when scripting. Under advanced options. "Script DROP and CREATE". This will drop the existing object and re-create the new one.

Comment: Also. You could just do a search and replace on your scripts and replace "CREATE PROCEDURE" with "UPDATE PROCEDURE".